# TypeError("'functools.partial' object is not iterable",) in python, bottle.py

Tags: python, bottle

Below is my code, stripped to what's causing the error.
I am trying to use python and bottle framework. 
When trying to launch localhost, I get this error saying that functools.partial is not iterable.
HELP?

my html code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Home Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <section>
                <ul>
                    %for i in include:
                    <li>{{i}}</li>
                    %end
                </ul>
            </section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

my bottle code.

```
        import bottle

    @bottle.route('/')
    def home_page():
        __include = ['Uppercase characters', 'Lowercase characters', 'Symbols', 'Numbers']
        return bottle.template('template', {'include' : __include})

    bottle.debug(True)
    bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: `bottle.template('template', include=__include)`

Comment: I tried that too before posting here because you can pass the variable or a dictionary, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call it "include" - it is reserved by SimpleTemplate

just rename it

```
@bottle.route('/')
def home_page():
    include = ['Uppercase characters', 'Lowercase characters', 'Symbols', 'Numbers']
    return bottle.template('template', {'include_or_other_name' : include})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <ul>
                %for i in include_or_other_name:
                <li>{{i}}</li>
                %end
            </ul>
        </section>
    </body>
   </html>
```